# Iterating over an array Vs Mapping solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js, mapping

Which of the two is more efficient.
Assuming I have this,

```
uint[] public availableRooms = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
```

And I need to know whether 5 is present in the array above. Which of the two is more efficient and can you help with how to do that with mapping?

Edit.

Based on the comments by users, a mapping will be the best way to find out if an element exists or not. So I changed the code into something like this

```
mapping (uni256 => bool);
```

And in the constructor function, I constructor all instances of my availableRooms

```
constructor (){
availableRooms[1] = true;
availableRooms[2] = true;
availableRooms[3] = true;
availableRooms[4] = true;
availableRooms[5] = true;
availableRooms[6] = true;
availableRooms[7] = true;
}
```

And now to find out if the room really exist, all I have to do is

```
availableRooms[5] ;
```

Comment: Iterating in solidity is very expensive and also limited to max number until u go out of gas. Mapping cannot be iterated easily u need to use some weird tricks to do that. Maybe the best way is to see the openZeppelin library contracts and see how are they handling iterations and arrays. I remember the erc721enumaration contract of them have something like that or need something like that

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can do this easy with a map.

```
mapping(uint8 => bool) public availableRooms;
```

uint8 is a number of the room.
bool is a false/true , depending on if the room is available.

If you want to check if room number 5 is available you just need to call the map.

`availableRooms [5];` //And you will get true or false

Comment: Does that mean, I shouldn't put in an array? Or I should create a mapping that has the same identification  as the array?

Comment: If you wish to know if an element is in the list. Then mapping is the way to go. Way more efficient. Because in a list you would have to iterate over it and compare elements until you find a match.